# Cut a file based on a text marker

Tags: shell

I have a text file that has the following layout:

```
text
text
..
CUT HERE
text
text
..
```

The literal `CUT HERE` appears only once. What I want to do using shell scripting, is to produce another file containing all the text below `CUT HERE`, i.e. ignore whatever above `CUT HERE`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '0,/CUT HERE/d' file > new_file
```

Comment: Thanks that would do the job.